# PDF editor that can arrange pages visually (on a page-thumbnail grid...)

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, portable, pdf-editor

I'm looking for a Windows freeware that:

1. can remove a page (example: remove page #7 from a 50-page PDF, and save the result as PDF)
2. can move a page (example: move page #23 from a 50-page PDF to the end of the file)
3. can extract a page (example: extract page #11 into a new PDF)
4. can rotate pages
5. **can do all these things visually**, like in Adobe Acrobat Pro (i.e. drag/drop pages in a page-thumbnails grid):

   [image]

I've tried:

- PDFCreator: doesn't allow condition 5 (visual edition), because, for example, it requires to open the PDF document, *Print*, Choose *PDFCreator*, "Page: 1-6;8-50" to remove page #7
- [PDFArchitect](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfarchitect/personal): the basic version is free, but the one that allows conditions 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 is not freeware. [More specifically, the free version allows 1, 2, 4, 5, but extracting a page is not possible, a popup suggesting to [upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEKY4.jpg) is displayed].
- [PDFSam](https://pdfsam.org/): idem, the version that allows condition 5 is [PDFsam Visual](https://pdfsam.org/en/download-pdfsam-visual/), not free
- [PDFill](https://www.pdfill.com/pdf_tools_free.html): condition 5 not met
- pdftk: idem

Note: a portable tool would be great!

Note2: please provide a screenshot in your answer, so that it can be useful for all users

Comment: In case of PDFArchitect wouldn't a workaround be: remove all pages except the page you want to keep and save the document under a different name? (Didn't check as I don't have PDFArchitect installed).

Comment: Yes that's what I do for now, you're right, it works well, until I find a better solution.

Comment: [PDF-Shuffler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/) is what you are looking for and also FOSS, but does not provide binaries for windows what i guess you are using, although this information is missing...

Answer (score 2):

NAPS2 is a free, open source Windows application (with experimental Linux support in beta), available in both installer and portable forms. I believe it does everything you want it to. While it was originally intended for scanning, you can import a PDF (drag and drop) and then add, remove, and reorder pages. You can then reexport as PDF. If you want to extract pages, you can hold down control, select the pages you want to extract, release control, and press the down arrow next to Save PDF to save just the selected pages. NAPS2 also has an OCR feature that can run on PDF pages that don’t already have recognized text in them.

Only downside I know of is that it doesn’t update automatically, but this is available in the About box in the beta version, available at https://github.com/cyanfish/naps2/releases.

https://www.naps2.com/download.html

Comment: I tried it, it's quite good, but it doesn't really "open" PDF, but rather it "imports" PDF (quite long task for a > 10 pages PDF) into a new canvas, and recreates a new PDF at the end. It probably reencondes the images?

Comment: @Basj I don't remember it taking that long to process a PDF for me, but the OCR feature can be slow sometimes. You could try disabling that if you have it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I have 3 suggestions:

**First**: [PDFescape](https://www.pdfescape.com/windows/)

[image]

Can do items 1, 2, 4 and 5. Free, online (portable) and does not leave a watermark. Do not need to create a profile, or a subscription. Just upload your PDF, edit it however you wish and download again.

**Second**: [PDF-XChange Editor Plus](https://www.tracker-software.com/)

[image]

It is not free, but hold on, it can do all you wish, plus there is a portable version and it is only (at the moment of this post) a one-time purchase of $54.50, much cheaper than the rest. One-time **no subscription** (which allows for a one year free update/upgrade period), so I seriously suggest to take a look into it.

Third: [LibreOffice Draw](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/)

[image]

Covers most of your requirements (except item 3, the catch is that depending on the PDF, there may be some formatting issues, as LibreOffice Draw converts your PDF and then exports it as a PDF again.

Comment: The first (I tested the standalone desktop version) doesn't do all of that (see https://www.pdfescape.com/signup/?selplan=premium), it requires the Premium or Ultimate (36$ / yr or 72$ / yr). About online version: I'm not looking for an online tool but desktop standalone.

Comment: If the second is > $50, and more generally if it's not free, then I prefer to buy once for all the reference software "Adobe Acrobat XI Pro" for 34€ [here](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/Adobe-Acrobat-XI-Pro-Windows-PC-Download-Version/282975769232?hash=item41e2ab9290:g:m48AAOSwj2RbAusb).

Comment: Iw as actually suggesting the web/online version of PDFescape, but I understand, a shame I couldn't help you. Cheers!

Comment: Not so sure, but I would still pay >50 to have a portable PDF editor in my pocket. :) I also updated the suggestions to include LibreOffice Draw, it is also portable (I like portable software).

Comment: Side remark: PDFEscape seems to be another branding of [PDFArchitect](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfarchitect), they have the same marketing (Free with lots of ads, and every little additional feature needs subscription/payment) and exact same UI ;)

Comment: I did think they were similar and gave me the feeling of "keep away" but never thought they would be from same devs. More suspicious now.

Answer (score 0):

PDFArranger.
https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger

Apart from their crazy menu (What is wrong with "File > Open"?), it is an excellent tool.

It does exactly what you are looking for, and it feels really nice.

[image]

[image]