# PDF rotate for Windows

Tags: windows, open-source, pdf, pdf-editor

I am looking for a PDF editor that can:

- rotate
- add text

ideally this would be open source, but freeware is acceptable - i would prefer to avoid anything that requires Java - as I dont want to install Java

Comment: Are you looking for an application, or an SDK? You mention Java, but not sure if you just mean JRE or Java coding.

Comment: [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) can somehow import (and afterwards edit) PDFs.

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Is there a free desktop pdf editor?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31467/is-there-a-free-desktop-pdf-editor)

Comment: Related: [PDF editor that can arrange pages visually (on a page-thumbnail grid…)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/49426/pdf-editor-that-can-arrange-pages-visually-on-a-page-thumbnail-grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with PdfCpu. Rotate example:

```
pdfcpu rotate in.pdf 90
```

Stamp example:

```
pdfcpu stamp add -p 1 -m text March 'pos:tc, rot:0, sc:1 abs' in.pdf
```

- https://pdfcpu.io/core/rotate
- https://pdfcpu.io/core/stamp

Answer (score 1):

pdf xchange viewer is freeware that I've been using for years, because it's the best windows pdf client I've ever found.
https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer
hidden gem that's been around forever, highly reputable, virustotal.com clear for years.

It opens very fast, free, no water mark, and can do both temporary and permanent rotations.

**Here's how temp rotation works:**
[image: temp rotation]

**Here's how perm rotation works:**
[image]

**Here's some additional context so you know how easy it is to use:**
I'm in the middle of doing my taxes so I used a "Brother-ADS-1200 Compact Desktop Scanner" (purchased for $90 on ebay love that thing, no drivers/software just scan straight to USB stick, scans fast and accurate.) to convert a 10 page physical document into a pdf.

The physical document was formatted where the first 2 pages were intended to be read in vertical/portrait orientation. And the last 8 pages were intended to be read in horizontal/landscape orientation.
I was able to easily permanently rotate the last 8 pages, so that when I open the pdf all 10 pages naturally have the ideal reading orientation.
Here's what the interface looks like when you click the button for permanent rotation:
[image: perm rotate interface]

Answer (score 0):

Xodo can do all this, and it is completely free (no ads, no in-app purchases)

- http://xodo.com
- http://microsoft.com/p/xodo-pdf-reader-editor/9wzdncrdjxp4

Comment: There is support/uservoice page that contains documentation for each platform. http://feedback.xodo.com/

Comment: That definitely should not be happening. Can you create a new SO question, or submit ticket here: https://www.xodo.com/support.html. Please clearly indicate your browser+os, and your exact steps to reproduce. Note that there is a windows xodo native app available from the store, if you prefer something installed.